# opening a module created in flex under ios app

Tags: ios, apache-flex

We are creating an ios app, In which we want to use certain interactive functionality which is created in flex. Though flex 4.5 does gives an option to create an ipa file and lauch it in app store as a app. But we want only a certain functionality in flex and want to develop other functionality using Objective C only. Is that possible? Can we use a module developed in flex inside an objective C app?

I have searched and found out that we can make .ane packages through flex. These packages use .a file to access the native ios functionality.

To know about Adobe Native extensions (ane) click [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html)

To see the sample provided by adobe click [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/vibration.html)

All I want to know is Can we include this ane in ios app, being developed using objective C using xcode 4? Is there any way I can use a module developed in flex under my cocoa app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANE is an Adobe Native Extension. The file like you say contains the Xcode static lib, but it also contains a SWC (which is a flex library), and this SWC is used to wire the Xcode to a Flex project. The ANE is included in a Flex mobile project, not the other way around.

The way I see it, you have two options here, pending on what exactly you want to achieve:

Your first option is to have a flex mobile app that calls your Xcode natively. Unfortunately Xcode cannot call Flex, only Flex can call Xcode. Think of the days of JNI. C couldn't call java, but you could simulate this behavior by having a java listener. Like so, your flex app could act as a listener and respond on whatever your objective-c code tells it to. Possibly one of the easier things would be to start off by displaying a native floating window in your flex mobile application. I've posted a writing on how to do this here: [How to create an ANE that will natively display a Floating Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968726/how-to-create-an-ane-that-will-natively-display-a-floating-window)

Your second option is to have two apps: one the flex mobile app that contains the flex functionality you require, and an Xcode app that contains the Xcode functionality you require. And then you let these two apps call one another by using custom application urls on both of them.