# How to create an ANE that will natively display a Floating Window

Tags: ios, xcode, apache-flex, adobe, air-native-extension

How to create a native window in Xcode and integrate it with a Mobile Flex application. The native window should act similar as the StageWebView component whereby the native content floats in a rectangular area over the rest of the Flex app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Being a flex programmer, this was a tedious process that took me weeks to figure out. Hope this will helps some other Xcode newbies.

First of all, you must have a basic understanding of Objective-C and Xcode. You should be able to create a simple Hello World Xcode program. Once you know how to do this, you'll see that for each visual window you'll typically have a xib file, a header file and an implementation file. I found that it is easier to start of writing a normal Xcode application, and then once it is working and looking like it should, you manually pull these 3 files (and of course the helper files) over to your Xcode static library project. So, moving on, I'm going to assume that you're past this step. Here are some step by step instructions on how to integrate Xcode and Flex mobile, using ANE:

- Open XCode. Create new project. iOS -> Cocoa Touch Static Library. I called my project FWAne
- Delete FWAne.h file. Replace contents of FWAne.m file with the following:

  ```
  '#import "FloatingWindow.h"
  '#import "FlashRuntimeExtensions.h"

  FREObject openFloatingWindow(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[] )
  {
      uint32_t parm0Length, parm1Length, parm2Length, parm3Length, parm4Length, parm5Length, parm6Length, parm7Length, parm8Length, parm9Length, parm10Length, parm11Length, parm12Length, parm13Length;
      const uint8_t *uparm0, *uparm1, *uparm2, *uparm3, *uparm4, *uparm5, *uparm6, *uparm7, *uparm8, *uparm9, *uparm10, *uparm11, *uparm12, *uparm13;
      FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &parm0Length, &uparm0);
      NSString* parm0 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm0];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[1], &parm1Length, &uparm1);
      //    NSString* parm1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm1];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[2], &parm2Length, &uparm2);
      //    NSString* parm2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm2];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[3], &parm3Length, &uparm3);
      //    NSString* parm3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm3];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[4], &parm4Length, &uparm4);
      //    NSString* parm4 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm4];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[5], &parm5Length, &uparm5);
      //    NSString* parm5 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm5];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[6], &parm6Length, &uparm6);
      //    NSString* parm6 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm6];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[7], &parm7Length, &uparm7);
      //    NSString* parm7 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm7];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[8], &parm8Length, &uparm8);
      //    NSString* parm8 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm8];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[9], &parm9Length, &uparm9);
      //    NSString* parm9 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm9];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[10], &parm10Length, &uparm10);
      //    NSString* parm10 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm10];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[11], &parm11Length, &uparm11);
      //    NSString* parm11 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm11];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[12], &parm12Length, &uparm12);
      //    NSString* parm12 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm12];
      //    FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[13], &parm13Length, &uparm13);
      //    NSString* parm13 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)uparm13];

  NSLog(@"Initializing delegate and window");
  id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
  UIWindow *window = [delegate window];
  NSLog(@"Creating FloatingWindow");
  FloatingWindow* fw = [[FloatingWindow alloc] initWithNibName:@"FloatingWindow" bundle:nil];
  NSLog(@"Adding FloatingWindow");
  [window addSubview:fw.view];
  NSLog(@"Setting frame size");
  fw.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
  NSLog(@"Done openFloatingWindow");
  return NULL;


  }

  // ContextFinalizer().
  void ContextFinalizer(FREContext ctx) 
  {
      NSLog(@"ContextFinalizer");
      //Cleanup Here.
      return;
  }

  // ContextInitializer()
  void ContextInitializer(void* extData, const uint8_t* ctxType, FREContext ctx, 
                          uint32_t* numFunctionsToTest, const FRENamedFunction** functionsToSet) 
  {
      NSLog(@"ContextInitializer");
      *numFunctionsToTest = 1;

  FRENamedFunction* func = (FRENamedFunction*) malloc(sizeof(FRENamedFunction) * 1);
  func[0].name = (const uint8_t*) "openFloatingWindow";
  func[0].functionData = NULL;
  func[0].function = &openFloatingWindow;

  *functionsToSet = func;


  }

  // ExtInitializer()
  void ExtInitializer(void** extDataToSet, FREContextInitializer* ctxInitializerToSet, 
                      FREContextFinalizer* ctxFinalizerToSet) 
  {    
      NSLog(@"ExtInitializer");
      *extDataToSet = NULL;
      *ctxInitializerToSet = &ContextInitializer;
      *ctxFinalizerToSet = &ContextFinalizer;
  }

  // ExtFinalizer()
  void ExtFinalizer(void* extData) {
      NSLog(@"ExtFinalizer");
      // Do Cleanup here.
      return;
  }
  ```
- Add the FlashRuntimeExtensions.h to your Xcode project. This file exists under the /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks/4.6.0/include folder
- Add FloatingWindow.h and FloatingWindow.m (or whatever the files are called that is associated with the owner of your xib) to your Xcode project.
- You might also need to add the UIKit framework to the xcode project (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework)
- Go to project build settings and modify the following flags (Failure to do so results in Segmentation fault. Took me a while to figure this out. Hope this is all the flags that I changed):

  1. Target device family = iPhone/iPad
  2. Mach-O Type = Static Library
  3. Other linker flags = -OjbC –v
  4. Expand Build settings in Info.plist file = No
  5. Enable Linking with shared libraries = No
- Build the Xcode static library
- Now, go to FlashBuilder and create a Flex library project. Be sure in include the Adobe Air libraries
- Create your class that will use ExtensionContext to wire the Flex code to your Xcode code like so:

  ```
  package fwane
  {
      import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
      import flash.events.StatusEvent;
      import flash.external.ExtensionContext;

  public class FWAne 
  {

      private static const EXTENSION_ID : String = "fwane.FWAne";

      private var context : ExtensionContext;

      public function FWAne()
      {
          context = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext( EXTENSION_ID, null );
          if (context == null) {
              trace("WARNING: ExtensionContext cannot initialize");
          }
      }

      public function openFloatingWeendow(fileName : String) : void {
          trace("Calling openFloatingWeendow");
          context.addEventListener( StatusEvent.STATUS, onAneWinHander );
          trace("Invoking native call");
          context.call( "openFloatingWindow", fileName);
          trace("Returning from openFloatingWeendow");
      }

      private function onAneWinHander( event : StatusEvent ) : void
      {
          trace(event.level);
      }

  }


  }
  ```
- Build the FWAne swc
- Next, you are going to require a build script to compile your ANE. Here's my build.sh script:

  ```
  export XLIB="/Users/christo.smal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wherever-lib.a"
  export CERT="/wherever/if/you/want/to/sign/ane.p12"
  export FLEXLIBPATH="../Path/of/flex/library/project"
  export XIBPATH="/Path/of/where/xib/files/are"
  export SWCFNAME="FWAne.swc"
  export ANEFNAME="FWAne.ane"

  ls -la $XLIB

  echo Copying files ...
   rm -rf debug/*
  cp $FLEXLIBPATH/src/extension.xml .
  cp $FLEXLIBPATH/bin/$SWCFNAME .
   cp $XLIB ./debug

  '# copy resource files such as images to debug folder
  cp /path/to/my/images/referenced/from/xcode/*.png ./debug

  echo Compiling xib''s

  cp $XIBPATH/*.xib ./debug
  cp /wherever/FloatingWindow.xib ./debug

  /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile debug/FloatingWindow.nib debug/FloatingWindow.xib --sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk

  rm -rf debug/*.xib


  echo Extracting library.swc ...
  cp $SWCFNAME kak
  cd kak
  unzip -xo $SWCFNAME
  cp -X library.swf ../debug
  cd ..

  echo Copying some more files ...
  rm -rf debug/*.ane
  cp extension.xml debug

  echo Building ANE ... 
  '#  -package -target ane / extension.xml -swc  -platform  -C  .
  /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/sdks/4.6.0/bin/adt -package -target ane debug/unsigned.ane extension.xml -swc $SWCFNAME -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions ios-platformoptions.xml -C debug .

  echo Signing ANE ...
  '#/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/sdks/4.6.0/bin/adt -sign -storetype pkcs12 -keystore $CERT -storepass password -target ane debug/unsigned.ane $ANEFNAME
  cp debug/unsigned.ane $ANEFNAME

  echo done
  ```
- Important to note about my build script: The xibs are compiled to nibs, and then these nibs together with other resource files (such as images) are then included in the ANE. Remember that static libs cannot contain resource files.
- You would also require an ios-platformoptions.xml file. This is to include all frameworks you require. You can also include any additional 3rd party libs with their search paths here:

  ```
  <platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
      <sdkVersion>5.0</sdkVersion>
      <linkerOptions>
          <option>-framework Foundation</option>
          <option>-framework UIKit</option>
          <option>-framework QuartzCore</option>
          <option>-framework CoreGraphics</option>
          <!--option>-lthirdparty</option>
          <option>-L/searhPath/for/thirdlibrary</option-->
      </linkerOptions>
  </platform>
  ```
- Now, in FlashBuilder, create a sample test application project. Go to project properties. In Flex build path, make sure the ane is added. Also under Flex Build Packaging -> Apple iOS -> Native extensions the ANE is added there and package is checked. Also add the Apple iOS SDK folder under native extensions. Finally, check that the extension is added in the -app.xml file.
- In FlashBuilder, create a debug configuration on device with the appropriate packaging settings. Double check that the native extension is included and packaged. Clean the project and debug. If all goes well the 'Waiting for debug connection' window pops up. Install and launch the app on the iPad.

Hope this helps

C

Comment: This is just amazing... thanks Christo.  You saved me several weeks of chasing my own tail.  This worked on Xcode 6 as well.